# Editing after saving doesn't show selected input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using the Backpack for Laravel CRUD features & currently having an issue with the `select` field type as to which after saving the form, once I go back to try and edit it isn't pre-defining my **selected** option?

Here's my `setup()` code inside my `Accounts` controller:

```
$this->crud->setModel("App\Models\Accounts");
$this->crud->setRoute("admin/accounts");
$this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('Accounts', 'Account');

$this->crud->addField([
    'label' => "Proxy",
    'type' => 'select',
    'name' => 'proxy_id',
    'entity' => 'proxy',
    'attribute' => 'id',
    'model' => "App\Models\Proxies",
    'nullable' => true
]);
```

And here's my `proxy()` entity within the `Accounts` model:

```
public function proxy()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Proxies::class, 'id', 'proxy_id');
}
```

Here's the `App\Models\Proxies` class:

```
class Proxies extends Model
{

    use CrudTrait;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'proxies';

    protected $fillable = [
        'ip',
        'port',
        'username',
        'password',
        'status'
    ];

    public function getStatusValue()
    {
        switch($this->status) {
            case "0":
                return '<span class="label label-success">Offline</span>';
                break;
            case "1":
                return '<span class="label label-success">Online</span>';
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here's my DB migration for the **proxy_id** column:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('accounts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('proxy_id')->nullable();
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have added `{!! $field['name'].' - '.old($field['name']).' - '.$connected_entity_entry->getKey() !!}` to a newly created file: **/resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/select.blade.php** and the result I'm seeing is:

```
proxy_id -  - 1
```

So it appears the `old()` function isn't working correctly?

Comment: `$this->hasOne(Proxies::class,'proxy_id' ,'id');` parameter is wrong.

Comment: @Laravel how? it works okay for me when it comes to accessing via `(Model)->proxy`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one  as you see here. `return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

Comment: @Laravel it doesn't have many? it has only 1 entity assigned to it

Comment: Same for hasone as well `'foreign_key'` first will be foreign key always and second will be `local_key`

Comment: @Laravel as expected, you was wrong `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'proxies.proxy_id' in 'where clause' `

Comment: Can you verify that the `proxy_id` is properly saved in the database when saving the record?

Comment: Can you show what your frontend code looks like? Specifically, the code which renders the selected option?

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes, it appears that the `proxy_id` is updated with an integer & corresponds correctly; my only assumption that could be causing this is the fact the IP has dots which could be causing confusion with the `if` statement when validating if it's a match?

Comment: Ahh, ok, are you saying that a value like `123.343.33.3` gets saved in the db like  `123343333`?  If so, you have 2 options, `1)` change your database column from an INT to a VARCHAR which will then store the periods with the  numbers as a string. `2)` write a custom field that removes the periods before comparing the values. Sounds like you probably want `1`

Comment: If that doesnt get you what you need, please post the code you use to create the 2  tables in your migrations

Comment: @DelightedD0D I've gone ahead & updated my question!

Comment: the output of `proxy_id -  - 1` would seem to indicate that the proxy_id field is not on the incoming model. are you certain that the record in your DB has a value for `proxy_id`?

Comment: can you verify that `proxy_id` is in your `Accounts` model's `fillable` array, and _not_ in the model's `guarded` array?